# TCL : find and remove all characters in a string from the first occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: tcl

I am a newbie in TCL and in need of a TCL method / utility / code which can find and remove all characters (including itself) in a string from its first occurrence in a string.

I have a string like below:

```
Func::set()->method();
```

In the above string  I need to find first occurrence of '(' and remove all it and after that so that the resultant string would be just:

```
Func::set
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
set the_string [regsub {\(.*} $the_string ""]
```

or if you're not familiar with regexp then you can do it the more traditional way:

```
set the_string [
    string range $the_string 0 [
        expr {[string first "(" $the_string]-1}
    ]
]
```

For further info, read the manual pages for [[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm)], [[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm)] and [[re_syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)].

Comment: I would add `$` to the end of the regex to make its purpose more clear. It would then look like `{\(.*$}`

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to use `split` and `lindex`:

```
set the_string [lindex [split $the_string "("] 0]
```

This is short and simple, but may do a lot of extra work if your string is very long.